# Android: How to place views in a grid layout

Tags: android, grid-layout, cells

I want to create a grid layout that would consist of 35 cells (7 rows and 5 columns) and place 6 image views that have equal width and height in the following (row, column) cell pairs if rows and columns are *zero-based*:

(1,1), (1,3), (3,1), (3,3), (5,1), (5,3)

Can I create this layout using XML? How do I do that? May anyone help? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

you can do it. you have to declare a TableLayout with 7 TableRows. Then you can place empty elements where you don't want anything and your images where you want them, always keeping 5 columns in each row.

Hope it helps.

Comment: This way I have to define it programmatically, because I want all cells to have the same area and so divide the device screen by code! By the way what do you mean by empty elements?

Comment: no you don't, by defining the same amount of elements in each row, they automatically match their width. That's the magic of TableLayout. What I mean about empty elements, is to place for example an empto textview,so if you want something on column 3 you place empty empty image empty empty. That way you have 5 columns and the width matches up.

Comment: Yes, I think you're right. This way I can define it in XML layout. Thanks.